# Avoid counting unfiltered results using COUNTIFS formula

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that I am working on that lists all the incidents reported in the office. There are multiple sheets, the original data sheet and others that extract that data.

I have a formula that currently counts how many incidents were logged as "Advertising" and "Call" for example. But I need this sheet to produce a monthly report, and I can do that by using the filter dates in the original sheet. However, when I filter the original sheet, the other sheet does not reflect the change (presumably the COUNTIFS function ignores unfiltered(hidden) records and counts them anyway.

Here's my current forumala;

```
=COUNTIFS(GES_OOH_Incidents!C2:C2004,"Call",GES_OOH_Incidents!D2:D2004,"Advertising")
```

Having looked around the web for a while, the only options I could really find was to create another column to return a value but I don't really want to do that.

Any suggestions/guidance/examples would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(GES_OOH_Incidents!C1,ROW(GES_OOH_Incidents!C:C)-ROW(GES_OOH_Incidents!C1),0)),(GES_OOH_Incidents!C:C="Call")*(GES_OOH_Incidents!D:D="Advertising"))
```

It's a slow formula applied on whole columns though.

[Got information from here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/851673-countif-function-to-exclude-hidden-cells.html)